# $f(0)=0$,$f(1)=1$,find the largest $u$ such that $\int_0^1|f'(x)-f(x)|dx \geqslant u$.

Tags: integral-inequality

> Suppose
>   $E=\{f\in C^1[0,1]$:  $f(0)=0$,$f(1)=1\}$.
>   Find the maximal $u\in \mathbb{R}$,such that forall $f\in E$,
>   \begin{align*}
> \int_0^1|f'(x)-f(x)|dx \geqslant  u.
> \end{align*}

I can prove that $u\geqslant \frac1e$,since
\begin{align*}
\frac1e=e^{-x}f(x)\Big|_0^1=\int_0^1e^{-x}(f'(x)-f(x))dx\leqslant \int_0^1|f'(x)-f(x)|dx .
\end{align*}
But I don't know how to find the  maximal $u$.